# GameKit Framework Out-of-order packets

Tags: ios

iam developing an IOS multiplayer game using

> GKSessionModeServer/GKSessionModeClient

with sending mode :

> GKSendDataReliable

i have read that "packets may not actually arrive in the order that you sent them" can anyone explain how could this happen and give example for it not code but brain Storming..

Comment: What is the source of that statement? Apple's doc (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008258-CH1-SW36) says this about `GKSendDataReliable`: Reliable transmissions are delivered in the order they were sent. Use this when you need to guarantee delivery.

Comment: "which means that no matter what, as long as the connection exists, that packet will be delivered with exactly the right contents. If the packet transmission fails, GKSession will try sending that packet again."

Comment: I'm sorry, but I missed the point you are trying to make in the comment above. I was asking about the quote `packets may not actually arrive in the order that you sent them`, which is not the case if you use `GKSendDataReliable`, according to Apple's documentation. So, can you please show the source of the `packets may not...` statement, as it clearly contradicts the official doc?